# Is there a device file explorer in VSCode?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode as my IDE. Is there a "Device File Explorer" in VSCode just like in Android Studio?

Comment: No answers.... So I assume there isn't one ????

Answer (score 4):

There is none. The tools available at your disposal currently are the devtools which run in a browser and embedded in VScode for the latest version 1.20
Android Studio/IntelliJ are dedicated IDEs to develop Android applications and hence have low level functionality to interact with the file system of Android Virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an easy solution even in 2021.

At the end I do the following

```
adb shell
su
cd <where ever I wish>
```

At least I can check the files that I have created

to download

```
adb pull <source> <destination>
```

Comment: `su` won't even work if your emulator image has Google Play. :/